# AS3 URLRequest Timeout (not AIR)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timeout, urlrequest

I am building a web-app that should send some data to the server.
Flash has a built in timeout limit for URLRequest set to 30 seconds.
I cannot use AIR (as this solution should run from the browser) and sometimes
the request is for more than 30seconds.

Flash ignores any data received after 30 seconds and sends an IO Error event although when I check the server, the script would have been executed.

Is there any solution to modify the timeout limit?
Maybe a smarter way? (any libraries to divide a huge request into smaller chunks and verify they are sent to the server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to register JS callback and use requests from JS.

Comment: @user557996: you are supposed to accept this as the correct answer, then