# Increasing timeout for URLLoader on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, urlloader

The timeout value of URLLoader on an iOS AIR application seems to be less than 5 seconds (how to I find out the exact value?). If a request takes more than that, an IOErrorEvent is raised.

How do I increase the timeout value? There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2691495/1305362) for setting it on IE, but how about iOS AIR applications?

Comment: This might be tricky for sure currently looking for this value.

Comment: Added the solution for you in the answer on this page.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Adobe Air ActionScript 3 SDK

*Increasing timeout for URLLoader on iOS* - You may need to use this lib instead.  It uses a [socket timer setting](https://github.com/stephenlb/pubnub-actionscript/blob/master/com/pubnub/PubNub.as#L206) which increases the timeout.  You will want to use this brand new rewrite of the AIR (Adobe) Flash SDK which offers a massive improvement on performance and reliability.  Built for Flash AS3.

> **View on GitHub: https://github.com/stephenlb/pubnub-actionscript**
>
> **Download ZIP File: https://github.com/stephenlb/pubnub-actionscript/archive/master.zip**

#### Simple Example

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import com.pubnub.PubNub;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        public function Main() {

            // Setup
            var pubnub:PubNub = new PubNub({ message : function message(
                message:Object,
                channel:String,
                timetoken:String,
                age:Number
            ):void {
                trace('message:',message);     // Message Payload
                trace('channel:',channel);     // Channel Source
                trace('timetoken:',timetoken); // PubNub TimeToken
                trace('age:',age);             // Aproxmate Age
            } });

            // Add Channels
            pubnub.subscribe({ channels : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] });

        }
    }
}
```

#### Import PubNub Client

```
import com.pubnub.PubNub;
```

#### Full Init PubNub Client

To see full usage example, visit the `Main.as` file.

```
var pubnub:PubNub = new PubNub({
    publish_key   : "demo",              // Publish Key
    subscribe_key : "demo",              // Subscribe Key
    drift_check   : 60000,               // Re-calculate Time Drift (ms)
    ssl           : false,               // SSL ?
    cipher_key    : 'mypass',            // AES256 Crypto Password
    message       : message,             // onMessage Receive
    idle          : idle,                // onPing Idle
    connect       : connect,             // onConnect
    reconnect     : reconnect,           // onReconnect
    disconnect    : disconnect           // onDisconnect
});
```

#### Add Channels

```
pubnub.subscribe({ channels : [ 'b', 'c' ] });
```

#### Remove Channels

```
pubnub.unsubscribe({ channels : [ 'b', 'c' ] });
```

#### Publish Message

```
pubnub.publish({
    channel  : 'b',
    message  : 'Hello!',
    response : function(r:Object):void {
        trace('publish:',JSON.stringify(r));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was inspired by [this line](https://github.com/stephenlb/pubnub-actionscript/blob/master/com/pubnub/PubNub.as#L206). Now the timeout works.